# Text contents in :before/:after of <select>

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I need to add custom text to `:before` and `:after` `<select>` element. 
But it does not seem to be working.

Please help.

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/cpwkg0vu/2/

Answer (score 1):

Select tags doesn't allow :after or :before pseudos that's why you have to wrap it with any element assigning it pseudos  elements

```css
#count {
  margin: 20px;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: 'Show ';
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: ' rows';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <select id="count">
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
    <option value=50>50</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select id="count">
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
    <option value=50>50</option>
    <option value="All">All</option>
  </select>
</div>

#count {
  margin: 20px;
}

    .wrapper:before {
      content: 'Show ';
    }

.wrapper:after {
  content: ' rows';
}
```

Comment: I cannot wrap it in any other element as this `<select>` is inserted by a plugin. Only thing that I can do is modifying it via CSS.